# C++ Storing maze to array

Tags: c++

I am a beginner at handling characters - This is likely a rookie mistake. I have a maze that looks like

```
###################
#                 #
# * * * * *\* * * #
#                 #
# * * * * * * * * #
#                 #
###################
```

This maze forms a grid with the top left being at the coordinate (0,0). I am trying to store each element of the maze into an array for processing. My current implementation looks like

```
// Print the world without the following spam and save it to an array
// Create array for storing the world and initialise
char world[width][height];

int i=0;
while(getline(infile, line)){
while(getline(infile, line)){
 int y=0;
 while(y<width){
  world[i][y]=line.at(y);
  cout << i << "," << y << "," << world[i][y];
  y++;
 }
i++;
if(i==height){break;}
}

cout << "backslash?:" << world[2][11] << endl;
```

The output to the terminal is as follows.

```
0,0,#0,1,#0,2,#0,3,#0,4,#0,5,#0,6,#0,7,#0,8,#0,9,#0,10,#0,11,#0,12,#0,13,#0,14,#0,15,#0,16,#0,17,#0,18,#
1,0,#1,1, 1,2, 1,3, 1,4, 1,5, 1,6, 1,7, 1,8, 1,9, 1,10, 1,11, 1,12, 1,13, 1,14, 1,15, 1,16, 1,17, 1,18,#
2,0,#2,1, 2,2,*2,3, 2,4,*2,5, 2,6,*2,7, 2,8,*2,9, 2,10,*2,11,\2,12,*2,13, 2,14,*2,15, 2,16,*2,17, 2,18,#
3,0,#3,1, 3,2, 3,3, 3,4, 3,5, 3,6, 3,7, 3,8, 3,9, 3,10, 3,11, 3,12, 3,13, 3,14, 3,15, 3,16, 3,17, 3,18,#
4,0,#4,1, 4,2,*4,3, 4,4,*4,5, 4,6,*4,7, 4,8,*4,9, 4,10,*4,11, 4,12,*4,13, 4,14,*4,15, 4,16,*4,17, 4,18,#
5,0,#5,1, 5,2, 5,3, 5,4, 5,5, 5,6, 5,7, 5,8, 5,9, 5,10, 5,11, 5,12, 5,13, 5,14, 5,15, 5,16, 5,17, 5,18,#
6,0,#6,1,#6,2,#6,3,#6,4,#6,5,#6,6,#6,7,#6,8,#6,9,#6,10,#6,11,#6,12,#6,13,# 6,14,#6,15,#6,16,#6,17,#6,18,#
backslash?:
```

Why does the final cout not show a backslash?

Comment: could you include the outputs in your question as well?

Comment: Could you make this a standalone program? We still don't know e.g., how you initialize `world`, or the definitions of some variables (`i`, `height`, `width`, ...).

Comment: I have added more information. I checked weight and height are calculated properly in this case and they are - (19 and 7 respectively).

Comment: could you iterate over `world[2]` row and post the output here? if everything went well, it should print `# * * * * *\* * * #` at index 2

Comment: The output was `# * * *#      # * *` which does not agree with the initial output from the above loop.

Comment: Please make this a [mcve].   And the reason no backslash is written is -- ... we don't know since we don't know what is in that file you're reading.  Well, we do know -- the character located at `world[2][11]` isn't a backslash.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have height and width transposed in this declaration:

```
char world[width][height];
```

So the shape of your array does not match your input. This means that you are writing outside the bounds of your array (which is Undefined Behavior) and probably overwriting some data.

Comment: ahh thats embarrassing :( Thank you.